# Symfony/ Doctrine: ManyToMany Relation and SQL exception

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I've defined in my Symfony application a ManyToMany Relation between the Entities 'Slideshow' and 'Slide'.

**Entity Slide (excerpt):**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="slide")
 */
class Slide {

/* [...] */

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Slideshow", inversedBy="slides", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="slides_to_slideshows",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="slide_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="slideshow_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $slideshows;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->slideArticle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->slideshows = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/* [...] */

/**
 * Add slideshow
 *
 * @param Slideshow $slideshow
 *
 * @return Slide
 */
public function addSlideshow(Slideshow $slideshow)
{
    $this->slideshow[] = $slideshow;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slideshows
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getSlideshows()
{
    return $this->slideshows;
}

/**
 * Remove slideshow
 *
 * @param Slideshow $slideshow
 */
public function removeSlideshow(Slideshow $slideshow)
{
    $this->slideshows->removeElement($slideshow);
}
}
```

**Entity Slideshow (excerpt):**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="slideshow")
 */
class Slideshow {

/* [...] */


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Slide", mappedBy="slideshows")
     */
    private $slides;           

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->slides = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

/* [...] */

    /**
     * Get slides
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getSlides()
    {
        return $this->slides;
    }

    /**
     * Add slide
     *
     * @param \Screensolutions\Macms\FrontBundle\Entity\Slide $slide
     *
     * @return Slideshow
     */
    public function addSlide(\Screensolutions\Macms\FrontBundle\Entity\Slide $slide)
    {
        $this->slides[] = $slide;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove slide
     *
     * @param \Screensolutions\Macms\FrontBundle\Entity\Slide $slide
     */
    public function removeSlide(\Screensolutions\Macms\FrontBundle\Entity\Slide $slide)
    {
        $this->slides->removeElement($slide);
    }
}
```

When I make a DB query, I get this error message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
>   t0.deleted AS deleted_2, t0.title AS title_3, t0.link AS link_4,
>   t0.rank AS rank_5, t0.artist_id AS artist_id_6 FROM slide t0 WHERE
>   slides_to_slideshows.slideshow_id = ? ORDER BY t0.deleted ASC, t0.rank
>   ASC, t0.title ASC' with params ["2"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'slides_to_slideshows.slideshow_id' in 'where clause'

The table *slides_to_slideshows* exists, the field *slideshow_id* as well, so I guess something's wrong with my definition of the relation. I wonder why the query is *slides_to_slideshows.slideshow_id* instead of *FROM slide t0, slides_to_slideshows t1 WHERE t1.slideshow_id*?

Any hints?

best regards

---

EDIT:
This is one query that provokes the error:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontBundle:Slide');
$slidesAll = $repository->findBy(array('slideshows' => $id), array('deleted' => 'ASC', 'rank' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'));
```

As suggested by Cerad I made a test with a simple findAll() query and that works flawless. The problem is the where clause *'slideshows' => $id*, so I suppose there´s something wrong with the definition of the relation.

The cache was cleared at least a thousand times, the database was updated by *doctrine:schema:update --force* and *doctrine:schema:validate* does not report any problems with this entities.

Any suggestions? I'm thankful for every hint - this problem makes me insane :(

Comment: Did you make sure to clear your cache? What does `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` print?

Comment: In Doctrine ORM you never have more that one table in the FROM clause.  The rest of the tables will be linked using JOIN statements.  Did you do anything unusual in your query?  Does a simple find work? Verify that you have no old mapping files under AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine which would interfere with your annotations.

Comment: You should post the actual query that gives you the error

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I´ve updated my question with more information.

Comment: You defined a unidirectional relation.  Pretty sure you need a bidirectional relation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: As mentioned by @Cerad I altered the entities and defined a bidirectional relation. Unfortunately I get the same error: "InvalidFieldNameException: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'slides_slideshows.slideshow_id' in 'where clause'".
The table  _slides_slideshows_ exists and the field _slideshow_id_ too.

Comment: Amy mapping files under AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine?

Comment: Nope. The whole application doesn't contain a file/ folder named _doctrine_.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontBundle:Slide')->createQueryBuilder('s')
->join('s.slideshows', 'sw')
->andWhere('sw.id=:id')->setParameter('id', $id)
->addOrderBy('s.deleted', 'ASC')
...
```

Comment: Thanks foryour answer! This _queryBuilder_ query works: 
`$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontBundle:Slide');
$slidesAll = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->leftJoin('s.slideshows', 'ss')
                ->where('ss.id=:id')
                ->orderBy('s.deleted', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('s.rank', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('s.title', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();`